# Database structure for three entities

Tags: database

I am new to working with dbs and am hoping this is a fairly common problem.  I have users, clients, and projects.  Users have many clients, clients have many projects, but users can only see SOME of a client's projects.  I have a users table.  I have a clients table with a user_id column, thus I can associate clients with a user.  I have a projects table with client_id column, thus I can associate projects with a client.  How can I associate a subset of a client's projects to a particular user.  So client_xyz has project_a, project_b, and project_c. user_1 should only see project_a and project_c of client_xyz.  I could add an additional column to the projects table called user_id, but this could quickly grow huge if I have 100 users and 100 projects.  How should I set up the db?  Am I over-complicating it?  This is Rails 3, I am using Active Record and SQLite.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a table having `project_id` and `user_id` fields.  Each record in this table will associate one client to one project.  You can associate as many clients to a project as you want, or as many projects to a client as you want.